# Scraping a website made with ICEfaces (session expired on consecutive ajax POST requests)

Tags: ajax, node.js, session, web-scraping, icefaces

I'm trying to scrape a website created with the ICEfaces web framework via a node.js script. I've managed to handle the login just fine, and then get some data from the main page (namely ice.session and ice.view, along with the JSESSIONID cookie returned by the login response).

The problem I've run into is when I try to do an AJAX POST request to the /block/ URLs. If I do the request by itself, it returns some data (just not the data I need), but if I do it after any other request, I get `<session-expired/>` as a result. It doesn't even matter which of the ICEfaces /block/ URLs I send the request to (I've tried with /send-receive-updates, /dispose-views, and even /ping). I've even tried the same request twice in a row just for kicks, and I always get a `<session-expired/>` response in return on the second one. I've monitored the requests when I browse the page with Chrome, and as far as I know I'm sending all the correct form data (as well as the correct headers). The page works just fine when I load it in the browser, so there must be something I'm not doing right.

---

Apparently, the order in which you do the requests matters in ICEfaces (i.e. it's not stateless, which kind of makes sense I guess). I just moved the requests around and finally got the response I desired.

Comment: Can you describe a bit better what you actually did to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> IceWindow, IceView and ViewState

Need to be passed as a parameter whenever you do an ajax submit.

Managed bean takes the previous instance of the current view view using ViewState value.

Comment: Apparently the framework version used for the site doesn't use ViewState, because I can't find it anywhere on the DOM nor in any of the POST request forms (only ice.session and ice.view get sent as form fields)